# Recording OUTGOING CALL and INCOMING CALL in ANDROID

Tags: android, audio, android-sdcard, mediarecorder

I have found many question about this issue but i am not clear at all.
I want to develop and app so that it can record any outgoing call and Incoming call. I wrote this code below but its not working. Please help details explanation would be preferred.Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
public class serviceBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context mycontext;
    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mycontext=context;
        try {
            // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
            TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            //Create Listner
            TeleListener PhoneListener = new TeleListener();

            // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
            tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
        }

    }
    class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                StopRecording();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                startRecording();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    public void startRecording(){
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/RecordMyVoice.mp4");
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Prepared");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "ERR 1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "ERR 2");
        }
        recorder.start(); 
    }
    public void StopRecording(){
        recorder.stop();          
        recorder.release();
        Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Stop Recording");
   }

}
```

}

Comment: any errors? or something else

Comment: Yes. when i call someone or a call comes then it crashes..

Comment: can you post log here

Comment: @MehediHassan did you get the answer? Is your app records calls? Please post the answer if got it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer doesn´t fix Your problem, but it´s to long for a comment. Without seeing Logcat it´s hard to say, why You get an exception, but one thing I see is, that it maybe could give errors of Your release() call. So, if You call release() on a MediaRecorder object, it is in the null-state and can not used after that. So the problem is, You called

```
   final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

at the beginning. It would be a better practise to make the MediaRecorder Global

```
    private MediaRecorder recorder=null;
```

and create the Object in Your startRecording() method:

```
    private void startRecording(){

     recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                .
                .
                .

     }
```

Also, don´t forget to set permissions in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I got the problem .Actually the problem was with  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
I should write MIC instead of VOICE_CALL..
But when i write MIC the recording file was created but it was empty.

Comment: have You set the permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? Could You post the logcat output?